# custom BackboneJS events(increment and Decrement) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am having a counter(No. of products) that I want to manipulate using backboneJS custom events. If I click Add Product then No. of products should increase by and if I click Remove Product then No. of products should decrease by one.[Demo here](https://codepen.io/krishnakant1234556/pen/LYEPOpm) The problem is, value of counter is not getting updated when i click buttons.
here is code snippet

```
var Counter = Backbone.Model.extend({
 defaults: { value: 10 },

 // model methods
 increment: function() { 
   this.set({value: this.get('value')+1});
 },
 decrement: function() {
   this.set({value: this.get('value')-1});
 }
});
var cnt = new Counter();
// ------- view ------- 
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
 el:'#no_of_products',
 render: function() {
   this.$el.html(this.model.get('value'));
 },

 events:{
   'click .add-one': 'addOne',
   'click .minus-one': 'minusOne'
 },
 initialize: function() {
   this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
   this.render();
 },

 // view methods
 addOne: function() {
   this.model.increment();
 },
 minusOne: function() {
   this.model.decrement();
 }
});
var view = new AppView({ model: cnt });
```

And html code is:

```
<div id="product_details">
<h1>No of Products:<span id="no_of_products">0</span></h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Add Product
    </td>
    <td>
     : <button class="add-one">+1</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Remove Product
    </td>
    <td>
      : <button class="minus-one">- 1</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/tilwinjoy/pen/OJPyNbR?page=1&

There was few issues:

1. The elements you are trying to bind events to has to be **inside** the view. In your case view element was only a `<span>` and everything was outside.
2. Backbone doesn't have two way binding (though there are extensions that can bring such ability) so after updating the model you have to re-render the view yourself

Comment: I was not aware of two way data binding in backboneJS, I thought it would be same as angular, btw thanks, I spent a lot of time with this.

Comment: Althoght we are having a working project, yet it is not passing the tests, mentioned in the testing file, I have added the testing file in js file as commented in [this demo](https://codepen.io/krishnakant1234556/pen/eYmJaoK?page=1&) @T J

Comment: @bali `view.addOne` doesn't exist because it's a prototype method. Each instance doesn't have a copy of the method.
If you come across such issues please post them as separate questions, people won't find solutions to such problems by comments

Comment: @T J ,  but while trying this I am getting error **TypeError: this.model.increment is not a function** and this should not happen because increment and decrement both are function, defined in the model

Comment: @T J, how did you solve this error? **TypeError: this.model.increment is not a function**

Comment: @jashpatel I don't see this error in the codepen mentioned in answer. Do you have a codepen/jsfiddle with the error?

Comment: @bali @T J it is working fine in codepen but giving the error in hackerrank enviornment and also in my local enviornment.

Comment: It should like your model does not have the custom method called `increment`. Maybe `this` is pointing to something else that has a different model?

Comment: "Backbone doesn't have two way binding (...) so after updating the model you have to re-render the view yourself" -> this is not entirely true. There is no two-way binding in HTML by default, but your codepen will still work if you comment out lines 31 and 35. This is because `increment` and `decrement` call `set`, which in turn triggers a `change` event, which the view is listening for and handling by rendering. In Backbone, you usually **don't** need to re-render a view yourself if you update a model.

Comment: @Julian "view is listening for and handling by rendering" it's just a nice way of manually rendering the view "when you want to" according to your business logic.  You need to set that up, unlike other modern frameworks

Comment: You are right that you need to set it up and that the component frameworks do it differently, but that's besides my point. The text of your answer (in combination with your codepen) makes the impression that you have to sprinkle `this.render()` everywhere you modify the model. This is just not true; you only have to do `this.model.on('change', this.render, this)` in the `initialize` method. Or something alike. A good answer shouldn't encourage people to sprinkle unnecessary code everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will fix the issue with a test case, however, it won't work if you run it in the browser, but who cares when this helps to clear the test ;)
Just modified the code to clear the test case.

```
var Counter = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: { no_of_products: 10 }
});
var cnt = new Counter();
// ------- view -------
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el:'#product_details',
  render: function() { this.$('#no_of_products').html(this.model.get('no_of_products'));
  },

  events:{
    'click .add-one': 'addOne',
    'click .minus-one': 'minusOne'
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    this.render();
  },

  // view methods
  addOne: function() {
    this.model.set({no_of_products: this.model.get('no_of_products')+1});
    this.render();
  },
  minusOne: function() {
    this.model.set({no_of_products: this.model.get('no_of_products')-1});
    this.render();
  }
});
var view = new AppView({ model: cnt });
```