# Model method not identified

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

While trying out backboneJS hands-on, which expects me to implement two buttons *addOne* and *minusOne* that increase and decrease the value of one counter respectively, displayed on the same page - [Demo here](https://codepen.io/krishnakant1234556/pen/yLyaPeb)

I am getting the following error, even though I defined both increment and decrement methods in model definition:

```
TypeError: this.model.increment is not a function
```

I searched for this error and all I found related to this is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116014/custom-backbonejs-eventsincrement-and-decrement-not-working#), but this is not sufficient to resolve this error

Here is the full error:

```
Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 0 of 9 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
[1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 1 of 9 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.013 secs)
[1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 2 of 9 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.019 secs)
[1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 3 of 9 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.022 secs)
[1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) Second event Handson Testing Testing Event + and - no_of_users should be 10 FAILED
Expected '0' to be '10'. at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/index_test.js:31:42)
Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 4 of 9 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.027 secs)
[1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) Second event Handson Testing Testing Event + and - first addOne click should return 11 FAILED
TypeError: this.model.increment is not a function
        at child.addOne (app/index.js:29:35)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/index_test.js:34:8)
Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 5 of 9 (2 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.03 secs)
[1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) Second event Handson Testing Testing Event + and - first minusOne click should return 11 FAILED
        TypeError: this.model.decrement is not a function
        at child.minusOne (app/index.js:31:16)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/index_test.js:38:8)
Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 6 of 9 (3 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.033 secs)
[1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) Second event Handson Testing Testing Event + and - continous 2 addOne click should return 12 FAILED
TypeError: this.model.increment is not a function
        at child.addOne (app/index.js:29:35)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/index_test.js:42:8)
        Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 7 of 9 (4 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.036 secs)
        [1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) Second event Handson Testing Testing Event + and - continous 2 minusOne click should return 11 FAILED
        TypeError: this.model.decrement is not a function
        at child.minusOne (app/index.js:31:16)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/index_test.js:47:8)
        Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 8 of 9 (5 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.041 secs)
        [1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) Second event Handson Testing Testing Event + and - first addOne click and  minusOne click should return 10 FAILED
TypeError: this.model.increment is not a function
        at child.addOne (app/index.js:29:35)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (test/index_test.js:52:8)
Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 9 of 9 (6 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.044 secs)
[1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 9 of 9 (6 FAILED) (0.068 secs / 0.044 secs)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

**Note: Testing file is included as commented in java-script file**

Comment: Did you debug and check what is `this`? Maybe when you are running tests it is not the view instance, instead the test runner, `window` or something..?

Comment: sorry,but i didn't get you. I mean what you said.